# How can I modify props values once the page has been refreshed in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

[My code is he following:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4ecq.png)

I made this example. The thing is I want to access props values in onMounted() but if I console.log(account.value.date) it says undefined. So is there a way to modify props values before shown in template?

Thank you!

I just want to modify values I get from pops before they are shown in the page.

Comment: Please don't put code as images. Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) also [take tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You're using `account.date` as `v-model`. What do you expect to happen when the user types into the input?

Comment: What the user types is stores in account.date

Answer (score 0):

props in vue are read-only variables...
if you want to modify the value you can copy it to a data variable and then change it in onMounted hook or wherever you want.

if you still want to modify the prop itself you can do it by emitting to the parent component to make the change by himself